# Checking logged in user role in View in ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

A user in my web application may have several roles coming from different applications. Those roles are stored in the `HttpContext` in an array that is Serialized called Roles.

[image]

Currently for my controller I implement a custom filter that deserializes the array and reads the items within like this

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
            string[] applications = ListOfApplications.Split(",");
            string[] roles = ListOfRoles.Split(",");
            var userRoles = context.HttpContext.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "Roles").Select(c => c.Value).ToList();
            var matches = 0;
            foreach (var item in userRoles)
            {
                var currentItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserRoleDetailsViewModel>(item);
                UserRoleDetailsViewModel urdvm = new UserRoleDetailsViewModel
                {
                    Id = currentItem.Id,
                    Name = currentItem.Name,
                    ApplicationId = currentItem.ApplicationId,
                    ApplicationName = currentItem.ApplicationName
                };
                for (var i = 0; i < applications.Length; i++)
                {
                    if(applications[i] == ApplicationGlobals.All && roles[i] == RoleGlobals.All)
                    {
                        matches++;
                    }
                    if(applications[i]== ApplicationGlobals.All && roles[i] == urdvm.Name)
                    {
                        matches++;
                    }
                    if(applications[i] == urdvm.ApplicationName && roles[i] == urdvm.Name)
                    {
                        matches++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (matches == 0)
            {
                context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("Index", "Home", null);
            }
}
```

And I call it on top of my controller like this:

```
[Authorize]
[TypeFilter(typeof(ValidateRolesFilter), Arguments = new object[] {
        ApplicationGlobals.app1+","+ApplicationGlobals.app1
        ,RoleGlobals.SystemAdministrator+","+RoleGlobals.User
})]
```

However, this only works until the controller. How can I extend this to work in a view so that I am able to segment off areas in the navigation bar for example based on the users role? Is this possible?

Comment: Are you not using ASP.NET Core Identity?

Comment: Yeah I am but I my roles for each user have more information than what can be stored so I used custom claims

Comment: Actually you are trying to show and hide content based on logged in user and its role, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah. I'm looking at view components now but I'm wondering if there is another way?

Answer (score 2):

> However, this only works until the controller. How can I extend this to work in a view so that I am able to segment off areas in the navigation bar for example based on the users role? Is this possible?

Yes! possible. Following is the way of doing so in ASP.NET Core identity.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager // ApplicatonUser is the class that inherited IndentityUser
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

<ul class="navbar-nav">
    @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
    {
       // Here is navbar items for authenticated (logged in) user

       If(User.IsInRole("Admin");)
       {
           // Here is navbar items for only user with `Admin` Role
       }
    }
    else
    {
        // Here is navbar items for user if not logged in
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Your roles are in stored in `AspNetRoles` table and your `UserRoles` are stored in `AspNetUserRoles` table. Isn't it?

Comment: It isn't. I store my roles elsewhere

Comment: @JianYA Your  Role class is not inheriting `IdentityRole` class?

Comment: No. I use my own custom roles because I needed to extend it with more columns

Comment: You extended `IdentityRole` is not it?

Comment: I only extended IdentityUser. I did not extend IdentityRole

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188314/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-jianya).

Comment: Not the best example. why you need UserManager ? or even SignInManager ? why not just check if User is null if not then logged in, and then check roles.